# How to modularize the URL handling functions?

Tags: python, flask

With Python web application frameworks such as Flask, webapp2 and Pyramid, how can each route-handling-function can have its own py file? I don't want all these functions piled up together in a single file structure. What do I do to make this work in Flask, webapp2 and Pyramid?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In flask and pyramid (don't know about webapp2, but probably the same), route-handling-function (let's call them views) are nothing but function, that are register to an app registry.

---

In flask, you can put your view anywhere, as long as you register it :

app.py :

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
```

view.py :

```
from app import app
@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"
```

main.py :

```
from app import app
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

---

Same thing for pyramid. I won't go into the details. The registering process is different, but the idea is the same. But it anywhere, as long as you register it. There are two way to register views :

- using `add_view` : the first argument is the dotted path to the function. Put it anywhere, and put the right path here.
- Using `scan` : the first argument is a package that is scanned to find the views. Just make sure all your views are in the package and its subpackages, and everything will work.

Comment: Hi! Thank you. Great explanation. I shall be able to figure it out from here on. One question though, can I skip "@app.route("/")" putting it on the view.py but instead just define the function there, separate from route definitions? (e.g. central routing file, separate per-function-per-file structure)

Comment: Yes, flask has a method to register a route without using a decorator : http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.add_url_rule

Answer (score 1):

If Python expects functions in a particular place then you can import them yourself from other files.

For example, if the web framework imports functions from `code.py`:

```
def a():
    pass

def b():
    pass

def c():
    pass
```

then you can replace `code.py` with the following by importing the functions from elsewhere:

```
from mycode.somewhere import a, b
from mycode.some.other.place import c
```

As far as the web framework is concerned, your `code.py` still contains the function `a`, `b` and `c` but your code can certainly be organized in a different way.